# Sending json via jquery ajax not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm making an AJAX request and sending along some JSON:

```
 $(function() {
     var json = [{"id":"1", "area":"south"}, {"id":"2", "area":"north"},{"id":"3", "name":"east"},{"id":"1", "name":"west"}];

     jQuery.ajax({
         url: "index.php",
         type: "POST",
         data: {areas: JSON.stringify(json) },
         dataType: "json",
         beforeSend: function(x) {
             if (x && x.overrideMimeType) {
                 x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
             }
         },
         success: function(result) {
         alert(result);
         }
     });
```

and then I'm trying to use `json_decode` on the other end to decode it in to something useful for PHP:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['areas'])) {
        $json = $_POST['areas'];
        $obj = json_decode($json);
        var_dump($obj);
        exit;
    }
?>
```

The AJAX post gets made fine and if I put an echo inside the `if(isset$_POST)` I get it back so it seems it's getting sent. But I only get `Null` returned from the code. Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Comment: What do you get if you echo the `$_POST['area']` variable in your PHP script (without running its value through `json_decode()`)?

Comment: HI Jasper, If I print_r the post as you suggest I get an array back...Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [area] => south
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [area] => north
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => east
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => west
        )

) this makes no sense to me though. It shouldn't be an array before I decode it right?

Comment: You are creating a string from an object; jQuery is then taking your string and converting it to a query-string parameter; PHP is then taking that query-string parameter and turning it back into an object. This is the same behavior as using `[]` in the `name` attributes for a form to create an array. It appears as though the issue is that you are trying to create an object from an object (you tried to do too much!).

Comment: I'm not following. I thought this was the correct way to do it? Any ideas how to get this working?

Comment: If when you `print_r($_POST['areas'])` you get the structure you want, just don't do anything to it, remove the `$obj = json_decodE($json);` line or change it to `$obj = $_POST['areas']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>I believe you can just pass your `json` array directly to the AJAX function and skip the `JSON.stringify` function call:</s>

```
$(function() {
     var json = [{"id":"1", "area":"south"}, {"id":"2", "area":"north"},{"id":"3", "name":"east"},{"id":"1", "name":"west"}];

     jQuery.ajax({
         url: "index.php",
         type: "POST",
         data: {areas: json },
         dataType: "json",
         beforeSend: function(x) {
             if (x && x.overrideMimeType) {
                 x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
             }
         },
         success: function(result) {
             alert(result);
         }
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

If this is the output of the `$_POST['area']` variable from the PHP script before running `json_decode`:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [area] => south )
    [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [area] => north )
    [2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [name] => east ) 
    [3] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => west )
)
```

Then you don't need to run `json_decode` because you already have the object you want.

Comment: Makes no difference unfortuantely

Comment: Yes that's the case! But how? It makes little sense to me. I'm able to loop over and get results out also

Comment: The PHP parsing engine does this for you automatically. It's the same as making form inputs arrays by adding `[]` to the end of their name attributes (e.x. `<input type="text" name="some_text[]" /><input type="text" name="some_text[]" />`). Given these example inputs, PHP will give you an array like this: `$_POST['some_text'] =  Array ( [0] => '' [1] => '' )`

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
```

Also shouldn't `x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");` actually be `x.overrideMimeType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");`?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the amend. I've made those changes but still get back NULL from my var_dump above

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use stringify jQuery will take care of it. Try this.

```
$(function() {
     var json = [{"id":"1", "area":"south"}, {"id":"2", "area":"north"},{"id":"3", "name":"east"},{"id":"1", "name":"west"}];

     jQuery.ajax({
         url: "index.php",
         type: "POST",
         data: {areas: json },
         dataType: "json",
         beforeSend: function(x) {
             if (x && x.overrideMimeType) {
                 x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
             }
         },
         success: function(result) {
         alert(result);
         }
     });
});
```

Comment: Makes no difference unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
     var json = [{"id":"1", "area":"south"}, {"id":"2", "area":"north"},{"id":"3", "name":"east"},{"id":"1", "name":"west"}];

 jQuery.ajax({
     url: "index.php",
     type: "POST",
     data: {areas: JSON.stringify(json) },
     //dataType: "json",
     beforeSend: function(x) {
         if (x && x.overrideMimeType) {
             x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
         }
     },
     success: function(result) {
     alert(result);
     }
 });
```

You are dumping a response that is not a json, the dataType parameter tells the function what type of response to expect. If you don't put anything, it will give you what you expect, a var_dump from the PHP script. (This was verified with the code you posted).